# How to vertically align text within a section?

Tags: formatting

I am new to LaTeX, and I want to vertically align some text.

I have used a [template](https://github.com/sbrother/resume), and so far I have written this:

```
\section{\mysidestyle My\\Skills}
- How do I manage to get this line to align with the first word of the second line of text? It doesn't seem to align up? \\
- So that all of these lines sit flush\\
- And look presentable\\
```

The output is this:
[image]

How does one get the following output:

[image]
*Notice the* **H** *of* **How** *and the* **s** *of* **seem** *align vertically ie the indentation.* How could I do this?

---

**Addendum I:**

I already have previous *itemize*'d lists where the output is •. And I would like to keep them as is (ie:  •). I want to have another *itemize* function where this would work for dashes (ie: -).

---

**Addendum II:**
I would like the first line to be on the same line with My in "My Skills":
[image]
And not:
[image]

*The red line is for reference - and should be disregarded.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily do this with an `itemize` environment and changing the first level label (`\labelitemi`) inside the `itemize` environment you want:

```
\documentclass[margin,line]{resume}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

%\renewcommand\labelitemi{--}% < Setting the bullet as an en-dash GLOBALLY

\begin{resume}
 \section{\mysidestyle My\\Skills}

 \begin{itemize}
  \vspace{0mm}% < Aligns the first line of the "section" with the first "item"
  \renewcommand\labelitemi{--}% < Setting the bullet as an en-dash LOCALLY
  \item How do I manage to get this line to align with the first word of the second line of text? It doesn't seem to align up?
  \item So that all of these lines sit flush
  \item And look presentable
 \end{itemize}

 \begin{itemize}
  \item How do I manage to get this line to align with the first word of the second line of text? It doesn't seem to align up?
  \item So that all of these lines sit flush
  \item And look presentable
 \end{itemize}

\end{resume}
\end{document}
```

And the result is:

[image]

Comment: using the _\renewcommand\labelitemi{--}% < Setting the bullet as an en-dash_ changes all other "itemized" _dot points_ into dashes as well. I want 2 "itemized" lists - one as is - which is dots, and one for just dashes? how can I have two "itemize"s

Comment: In that case you just move the `\renewcommand\labelitemi{--}` inside the `itemize` environment you want to change. The effect of this change will hold until the `\end{itemize}`. I updated my answer to suit your needs.

Comment: How would I align the line of "- How do..." with the word "MY" of "MY SKILLS" , it seems to start off on the second line ie, "SKILLS - How do I.. "  please have a look at _Amendment II_

Comment: I have added \vspace{0mm} which has aligned the section with the first item, do you mind reprinting the output,

Comment: If that suits your needs, then there it goes...

Comment: is there a way that I can left shift the indentation as a variable from its current location, something like \moveindentleft{3mm} _and_ still keep all the alignment? [I have posted this as another question, but alas I'm still facing some issues!](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/407722/how-to-realign-itemized-sentences/407732#407732)

Comment: @3kstc Well, firstly, [Herbert's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/407732/134574) is correct for your **original** question, thus you should **accept it**. Second, the purpose of editing questions is to *clarify* or *improve* them in order to make it easier for people to solve **your problem**, and not to add a second question to it. Answered questions tend to be ignored by people willing to answer them, so it's unlikely that your "Amendment" will ever be answered. If you want to ask another question then just [ask another question!](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).

Comment: @3kstc That said, to do what you want you `\usepackage{enumitem}` and right beside the `\begin{itemize}` you put a `[leftmargin=<whatever-length-you-wish>]`. This option (and many others) can be found in the [`enumitem`'s package documentation at CTAN](https://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem?lang=en).

Comment: many thanks for all your help! Truly appreciate the feedback and advise! Sucks being a noobie in latex! :(