# How to realign itemize'd sentences

Tags: formatting

I am new to LaTeX, and I want to vertically align some text.I have used a [template](https://github.com/sbrother/resume), and I would like to learn how to realign the second line of an itemize'd list:

the code:

```
\section{\mysidestyle My\\Skills}
\begin{itemize}
\setlength{\itemindent}{-5mm}
\renewcommand\labelitemi{--}% < LOCALLY Setting the bullet as an en-dash
\vspace{0mm}
\item I can't seem to get all the second line of itemized items to align vertically. How could this be corrected that they align properly?
\item New items appear correct
\item It just happens when the line is very very very very very very very very long that there is a misalignment
\end{itemize}
```

output:
[image]

*I want the second lines to be aligned with the first. Indicated with red arrows.*

---

**Amendment I**

Using the following code:

```
\documentclass{resume}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\section{My Skills}
\begin{itemize}[label=--,before=\vspace{-\partopsep}]
\item I can't seem to get all the second line of itemized items to align vertically. 
    How could this be corrected that they align properly?
\item New items appear correct
\item It just happens when the line is very very very very very very very very long 
    that there is a misalignment
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Changes the format of what I want to achieve:

1. I would like to get `\item`'s indented further in (as illustrated above)
2. Move the "My Skills" title to the previous location (up)

Here is an illustration to better clarify what I want to do:
[image]

Comment: You have an answer here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/407711/how-to-vertically-align-text-within-a-section. But because you are hiding the class used, nobody can guess, what happens in your case.

Comment: Please complete your code into a minimal working example: include the document class used, relevant packages, and `\begin{document}`/`\end{document}` commands

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass{resume}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\section{My Skills}
\begin{itemize}[label=--,before=\vspace{-\partopsep}]
\item I can't seem to get all the second line of itemized items to align vertically. 
    How could this be corrected that they align properly?
\item New items appear correct
\item It just happens when the line is very very very very very very very very long 
    that there is a misalignment
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]